# Calculating width of checkboxes in NSOutlineView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm programmatically setting up a multi-column `NSOutlineView`. The first column contains only checkboxes whereas the other columns contain text. I'm creating the checkboxes like this:

```
cell = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
[cell setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
[cell setImagePosition:NSImageOnly];
```

Now I want to adjust the width of the first `NSTableColumn` to the exact width required by a checkbox. To calculate the dimensions of a checkbox cell, I do the following:

```
NSCell *cell = [m_view preparedCellAtColumn:0 row:0];
unsigned cellWidth = [cell cellSize].width;
```

This returns `18` in `cellWidth`. This is probably the right value but it isn't sufficient because `NSOutlineView` always seems to insert some blank space before the cells of the very first column. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see the checkboxes are currently cut off because the column width is too small because of the blank space in front of the checkbox.

Therefore, here is my question: How can I calculate the width of this blank space for my first `NSTableColumn` so that I can calculate the full column width required to show the checkbox and blank space? Is there maybe also a way to get rid of this blank space?

Comment: Looks like an outline view.

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes, it's an outline view of course.

Comment: The extra space is for the triangles.

Comment: Actually, further investigating into this problem led me to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063085/is-there-a-minimum-indentationperlevel-of-16

Comment: In other words: The cause of this problem seems to be that I can't set `indentationPerLevel` to anything less than 16 (except 0). It'll always insert  16 pixels padding space.

Comment: Where should the triangles go? `indentationPerLevel` is the indentation of the subrows. Maybe you can do something with `frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:`.