# Is there a minimum indentationPerLevel of 16?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I've noticed that setting `indentationPerLevel` to something smaller than 16 doesn't work with `NSOutlineView`. It always seems to indent by at least 16 pixels. I've tried to set `indentationPerLevel` to 4, 8, and 12 but the visible indentation is always 16 pixels, although `getIndentationPerLevel` returns the size I've set it to. The visible indentation, however, always seems to be at least 16 pixels.

An exception is setting indentation to 0. This works and removes the indentation. Setting it to 4, 8, or 12, however, will always result in an indentation of 16 pixels. So could it be that 16 is a minimum here?

Comment: Well, it sure sounds that way.  Sounds like you've answered your own question, no?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure because it *returns* the right value, i.e. the indentation I've set. But it *renders* at least 16 pixels... that's what's confusing me. If there was a minimum of 16, I'd expect it to return 16 for `getIndentationPerLevel` if the value I set it to was smaller than 16 but it doesn't. If I set it to 1, `getIndentationPerLevel` returns 1 although it renders an indentation of 16....